# Как установить минимальный Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian

Как установить дистрибутив с минимальным количеством пакетов, но чтобы при этом остались все основные пакеты, которые нужны для работы системы?

Пробовал через **netinstall**, **debootstrap**, но все ровно есть много пакетов, удалив которые, ничего не случится, и можно будет спокойно пользоваться системой.

Comment: А зачем именно нужна минимальная кофнигурация, меньшая, чем штатная? Что именно планируется запускать?

Comment: Это академический интерес или нужно добиться какой-то цели?

Comment: Может всё-таки расскажешь для каки именно задач? А то можно оставить только vmlinuz, initrd и grub. И это всё ещё будет debian. Вес кстати не больше 20мб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> есть много пакетов удалив которые, ничего не случится и можно будет спокойно пользоваться системой

совершенно верно — с **вашей** точки зрения.

ещё с чьей-нибудь точки зрения достаточно, например, лишь **загрузчика** (чтобы загрузить программу linux), **программы linux** и собранной статически какой-нибудь **интерактивной оболочки**. никакой пользы извлечь из такой «операционной системы» будет невозможно, но, формально, компьютер будет работать и даже как-то реагировать на вводимую информацию.

---

если вы точно знаете, какие пакеты не нужны **вам**, просто удалите их. вот и получите необходимый **вам** минимум.

---

ключевой момент в ваших рассуждениях: «ничего не случится». да, после удаления очередного пакета, скорее всего, ничего не случится. просто операционная система лишится части своих функций. если вам эти функции не нужны, смело удаляйте такие пакеты.

---

**перенесено из комментариев**

> хотелось бы готового способа

есть «готовый» способ, чтобы удовлетворить ваши требования:

1. удаляете пакет, который считаете «ненужным».
2. проверяете, работает ли то, что вам нужно. если не работает, возвращаете предыдущее **сохранённое** состояние.
3. повторяете с шага 1.

Comment: В каментах к вопросу пытаюсь выяснить то же самое. Пока безуспешно. Русские не сдаются.

Comment: @Виталий, я перенёс информацию из комментариев в ответ и удалил уже ненужные комментарии. что предлагаю сделать и вам.

Comment: Да, тестировать это лучше в виртуалке делая снапшоты перед каждым удалением "ненужного" пакета.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь получить систему с минимум пакетов, при установки не ставишь **не одной** галочки в менеджере пакетов. Потом ставишь aptitude (Удалить и потом сможешь). Убираешь флажок ставить рекомендаванные пакеты. Ставишь bysubox. Удаляешь все что есть в bysubox. Получишь почти минимальный дебиан, но абсолютно не удобный.(Самый минимальный когда вместо root initrd, но это уже клиника). А вот потом начинается самое интересное(Если я тебя правильно понял).
Надо поставить иксы и DE(или что полехче). Ставить нужно через Aptitude. И не в коем случае не виртуальные пакеты, так же проверять зависимости. В тех же иксах по умолчанию ставятся все драйвера на видео и устройство ввода. Тебе надо выбрать что то одно. После иксов ставишь DE(или что полехче). Тут схема примерно следующая(Расмотрим на примере Xfce) не ставить пакет Xfce а ставить например xfdesktop4, thunar и т.д. То есть необходимый минимум. **На установку таким способом у меня уходит часов 40-50**